# Capturing and interacting with table elements using Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, jquery-selectors, puppeteer

I am trying to loop through rows of a table, looking for text in `column-B` and then clicking a checkbox in `column-A`.

I am fairly new to Javascript and new to Puppeteer, so I apologize ahead of time if this is quite basic.

**My goal**
To locate all items in column 2 of my table and store to an array
To locate all items in column 1 of my table and store to an array
When the text I am interested in is found in the first array, click the element at same index of second array

I can identify all cells of column 2 in my table via css selector `.column-id`
I can identify all cells of column 1 (checkboxes) in my table via css selector `.select-item`

Following the Puppeteer docs, I can do the following to get the count of the elements found

```
const element = '.column-id'
const elementToClick = '.select-item'
const elementCount = await this.page.$$eval(element, (e) => e.length)
const eleToClickCount = await this.page.$$eval(elementToClick, (e) => e.length
```

Attempting to follow some of the examples I've found, I have the following code which I can 'make' work, but I don't feel it is correct, or at least, not the best way to accomplish what I'm after.

```
// Loop through elements searching for textToLookFor
    for (let i = 0; i < elementCount; i++) {
      const str = await this.page.$eval(
        `${element}:nth-child(2)`,
        (e) => e.innerText
      )
      // If string found, click element at same index as string
      if (str === textToLookFor) {
        await this.waitAndClick(`${elementToClick}:nth-child(${i + 1})`)
        foundMatch = true
        break
      }
    }
```

**Questions**

1. Am I storing the correct thing to my initial element variables?
2. Is using :nth-child(#) the correct way to do this?  Or is it not applicable in how I'm trying to use it?  This seems off as the nth-child of a given row would be the column (td), which is not what I'm after, but instead, the ith row as the iteration occurs through the for loop.

   I feel like this should be a very simple task and am clearly missing
   something.

   Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I've changed to using a selector of `table tr` instead of the class name and modified the code a bit and now it is working as I'd like and understand why.

```
async selectPresetNamed(name) {
    const tableRows = 'tbody tr'
    const rowCount = await this.page.$$eval(tableRows, (e) => e.length)

    // At least 1 row exists in table body
    if (rowCount == 0) {
        browser.close()
        throw new Error(`no elements found with locator, '${tableRows}'`)
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
      const str = await this.page.$eval(
        `${tableRows}:nth-child(${i + 1}) td:nth-child(2)`,
        (e) => e.innerText
      )
      if (str === name) {
        await this.page.waitAndClick(
          `${tableRows}:nth-child(${i + 1}) td:nth-child(1)`
        )
        break
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: [@bboursaw73](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6570550/bboursaw73) I want to get data from more than one tr (and in tr, I want to click 'a' tag and open this 'a' tag on a new page  )